# Currying a varargs proc and getting another varargs proc in ruby

Tags: ruby, clojure, currying

This is reasonably straightforward in clojure -

```
(def a (partial println "Hello:"))
(a "Bob")
(a "Bob" "Ganesh")
```

But this seems difficult in Ruby.

```
:puts.to_proc.curry(3)[Kernel, "Hello:"]("Bob")
:puts.to_proc.curry(4)[Kernel, "Hello:"]("Bob", "Ganesh")
```

Proc#curry doesn't seem to be able to return a varargs fn.

Of course we can

```
class Proc
  def partial(*left)
    Proc.new do |*right|
      self.call *left, *right
    end
  end
end
```

But I was wondering if this was in the standard library.

Comment: Please state the question so that it can be understood by those familiar with Ruby but not Closure. By "varargs fn" do you mean a curried proc with a variable number of arguments? For your example, what do you want the proc to return when called?

Comment: With an indefinite number, yes. Varargs is a language neutral term.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
:puts.to_proc.curry(3)[Kernel, "Hello:"].("Bob")
```

In ruby, bare parens only work to call methods.  For calling procs, you need to do either `.call()` or `[]` or `.()`.

Comment: Three ways? Five ways! `f = ->s { puts "Say #{s}!" }; f.yield("hey") #=> "Say hey!"; f === "hey" #=>  "Say hey!"`.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood? But this makes the code from your original post work